# Ticks disappear in Graphics3D with Epilog

Tags: plotting, bugs, graphics3d, ticks

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

Normally, you can enable `Graphics3D` to show tick marks by doing this:

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[], Axes -> True]
```

[image: ticks]

But in *Mathematica* version **10**, when I add an `Inset` which contains a `Grid` or `Column`, the output looks wrong:

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[], Axes -> True,
 Epilog -> Inset[Column[{"a"}], {.05, .05}]]
```

[image: no ticks]

The ticks only appear when I manually rotate the graphics or start editing the input line. But note that I produced the enclosed images here by doing `Export["file.png",%]` after each plot, so that this faulty display is indeed not just a notebook display problem - it leads to incorrectly exported graphics, too.

This doesn't appear to happen when the inset contains a `Row` instead of `Column`. I also see this strange behavior when doing something like this:

```
Plot3D[1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 Epilog -> Inset[Column[{"a"}], {.05, .05}]]
```

[image: partial ticks]

Here, you can see that the tick marks are displayed only *partially*!

My operating system is Mac OS X 10.8.5, and I am wondering if this is reproducible on other systems. If so, it would be nice to know how to work around this problem. The issue also goes away when the `Inset` only contains numbers and not strings.

**Edit**

I've reported this as a bug (CASE:1384605).

Comment: I can see this on OS X 10.9.4 with v10.  In v9 everything works fine.  I think this is a bug.

Comment: Confirmed in v10.0.0 under Windows.

Comment: V10 Windows - It also happens with `Grid`, but it doesn't happen with `Inset["a", {.05, .05}]`

Comment: When you click on the resulted plot the tick appears. anyone gets same behavior?

Comment: @Algohi Confirmed under Win7 x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the bug doesn't seem to occur when the `Inset` contains a `Row` instead of a `Column` or `Grid`, one could define the following function:

```
Attributes[fixInsets] = {HoldFirst}; 
fixInsets[plot_] := 
 ReleaseHold[
  Hold[plot] /. 
   HoldPattern[Rule[Epilog, Inset[x_, y___]]] :> 
    Rule[Epilog, Inset[Row[{x}], y]]
  ]
```

Then use it on the faulty plots like this:

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[], Axes -> True, 
  Epilog -> Inset[Column[{"a"}], {.05, .05}]] // fixInsets
```

This produces the correct output. All I did was to replace the content of the `Inset` (when it occurs in the `Epilog`) by `Row[{...}]` wrapping that content. `fixInsets` doesn't modify the plot if there is no need to, and it can be appended to any 3D graphics without having to change the actual plotting commands.

Another possible work-around is to wrap the plot in `Legended`. For example,

```
Legended[
 Plot3D[1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Epilog -> Inset[Column[{"a"}]]],
 ""]
```

This empty legend is enough to make the tick marks appear again.

Comment: +1 It even functions with `Inset[Style[Column[{"a", "b"}], 24, Red]`, so your solution seems to be a "general temporary fix"

Comment: @eldo Yes, the additional `Row` shouldn't be causing any trouble in any of the the cases I could think of.

Answer (score 3):

The bug is reproduced in v. 10.0.0 under Win7 x64.

A workaround:

```
Graphics[{Inset[Graphics3D[Sphere[], Axes -> True], Center, Center, 
   Scaled[1]], Inset[Column[{"a"}], {.05, .05}]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks - this gave me another idea: wrapping the plot in `Legended` instead of doing an inset works, too. I put this into my own attempt at an answer.

Answer (score 2):

While searching for a possible workaround I observed another strange behaviour:

Only functions in V9 (ticks disappear in V10):

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[],
 Axes -> True,
 Epilog -> Inset[Style["First row\nSecond Row", 12, Bold], {.05, .05}],
 ImagePadding -> 40]
```

[image]

But this functions in both versions:

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[],
 Axes -> True,
 Epilog -> Inset["First row\nSecond Row", {.05, .05}],
 ImagePadding -> 40]
```

[image]