# Problem with clipping of tick labels

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, version-10

Please look at

```
Show[DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[{Cone[]}]], Axes -> True, Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Well, there are some `Ticks`, but others are missing or (on the Z-axis) cut-off.

Now it becomes even worse:

```
dg = DiscretizeGraphics[Normal @ Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]] // Quiet

Show[dg, Axes -> True, Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

The `Ticks` are completely missing.

Is this a bug or do I overlook something?

**EDIT**

Thanks to hieron's answer:

```
Show[dg,
 Axes -> True,
 Boxed -> True,
 SphericalRegion -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{-3.2, 3.2}, {-2.4, 2.4}, {-2., 2.}}]
```

[image]

However, we don't need this work-around with

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that the numbers are cut-off? If so yes, I see the same.

Comment: Related?: [(57042)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57042)

Comment: I think you've found a bug in the way your discretized graphics are being scaled by `Show`.

Comment: BTW, you can extract the graphics you want to discrete without resorted to `Quit` with `dg = Cases[Normal @ Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}], GraphicsGroup[__], ∞][[1]] // DiscretizeGraphics`

Comment: My description of progress with *Mathematica*'s graphics capabilities, and the resulting user experience, is captured metaphorically by this Youtube movie: [Das Bild hing schief](http://youtu.be/MjcrfzSZQc8). Translation of the title (and the punch line at the end): "The picture was lopsided." Sorry couldn't resist since eldo probably knows this sketch.

Comment: @Jens "Everybody allows that to make a shoe you must have learned and practised the craft of the shoemaker, though every man has a model in his own foot, and possesses in his hands the natural endowments for the operations required. For philosophy alone, it seems to be imagined, such study, care, and application are not in the least requisite. This comfortable view of what is required for a philosopher has recently received corroboration through the theory of immediate or intuitive knowledge." (Hegel, Encyclopaedia of the Philosophical Sciences (1830), Introduction §5)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a bug, it happened already in recent MMA versions.
In such cases you can increase the value for option `PlotRangePadding`
Sorry, I can't test it, because I have actually MMA7.
Probably setting `SphericalRegion->True` or `ImagePadding` will help also

Comment: I had tried `PlotRangePadding` but it makes things even worse with `DiscretizeGraphics`.

Comment: Did you set PlotRange too?

Comment: I disagree with your assessment of eldo's problem not being a bug. I find that `Show`, given discretized graphics, is not scaling the image properly after rotation. During rotation, the graphics look fine, but as soon as I release the mouse button, bad scaling takes place.

Comment: @m_goldberg and the other two people who voted for his comment: then why did you not down-vote this answer?  That *is* what the down-vote is for after all; not spite or poor English, but an incorrect answer.  Use it accordingly.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I did not down vote because I am not 100% confident of my position. It's only my empirical observation, not the result of analysis. I thought a comment was appropriate, but nothing more. People are often very upset by a down vote. Also, I understand why you upbraid me, but why the up-voters? I would say they think the answer is correct.

Comment: @m_goldberg I respect that.  The voters I was referring to are the two people who agreed with your comment, *not* those who voted for the answer.  My point is that tacitly three people have expressed that this answer is wrong, yet it stands with a score of +2.